# combined SELECT with two mixed different criteria

Tags: mysql

I'm having problems selecting the data from the following example.

I have a dataset with contracts belonging to users that, in some cases, are overlapping in time (say, for current_date). Only when this overlap happens, I just want to know the latest contract signed. However, if one of the overlapping contracts is a 'test' (type = test), then I should take the valid one. The problem is that I can't figure out how to select this. Could anyone give me a hint?

So in this example

```
Table contracts
    START_DATE  END_DATE    USER_ID TYPE            CONTRACT_ID
    2015-09-17  2017-09-16  3193522 valid           318159780
    2016-09-21  2017-09-20  3193522 valid           318159779
    2015-11-26  2016-11-25  3510657 valid           319501137
    2016-09-20  2016-11-26  3510657 test            319501127
```

The desired output would be

```
    START_DATE  END_DATE    USER_ID TYPE            CONTRACT_ID
    2016-09-21  2017-09-20  3193522 valid           318159779
    2015-11-26  2016-11-25  3510657 valid           319501137
```

The dbms is MySQL. If they don't overlap I want to show them regardless their type. There are no overlapping contracts with the same start_date, this is controlled at application level.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: And if they are both valid and do not overlap?

Comment: I'd use a ranking query, giving an integer weighting (with a CASE statement, i.e. WHEN valid THEN 1 ELSE 2), then order by that rank and have a HAVING [rank] = 1.

Comment: What if there are two or more matching contracts with the same `START_DATE`, which one should be picked? What if all contracts that match the date are test, should you pick one of them at all?

Comment: The dbms is MySQL. If they don't overlap I want to show them regardless their type. There are no overlapping contracts with the same start_date, this is controlled at application level